Tiempo de espera agotado en petición SOAP PHP para FE de la DIAN Colombia
Estoy haciendo pruebas de conexión con al DIAN para facturación electrónica. Ya he hecho las respectivas pruebas en SOAP UI y en general todo funciona bien. Incluso he puesto el XML de la petición firmado directamente en SOAP UI (Sin configurar el certificado) y se recibe correctamente la petición y por ende obtengo una respuesta 200.
El lío lo tengo a la hora de implementar en PHP o cuando utilizo para POSTMAN.
Inicialmente me generaba un error porque no tenía definido el action, pero obtenía una respuesta como tal. Ahora al establecer el action, se agota el tiempo de espera.
Algo para agregar es que ese endpoint responde instantáneamente, el tiempo de espera se agota porque algo estoy haciendo mal en la petición. En SOAP UI responde sin problemas en menos de 1s
El xml utilizado es el suministrado por la DIAN
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wcf="http://wcf.dian.colombia">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <wcf:GetStatus>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <wcf:trackId>123456666</wcf:trackId>
      </wcf:GetStatus>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente: ($xmlDian es el xml anterior firmado)
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://vpfe.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xmlDian,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://wcf.dian.colombia/IWcfDianCustomerServices/GetStatus"',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($xmlDian),
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de qué pueda estar sucediendo?
Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Para quien pueda servir.
El error estaba en la URL de la acción al firmar el xml. Debía establecerse:
http://wcf.dian.colombia/IWcfDianCustomerServices/GetStatus

Si deseas hacer que PHP no sea tan estricto con tiempo de espera debes configurarlo para que el tiempo de espera se aumente, pero esto es a nivel de servidor, aqui una fuente que habla sobre el tema:
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/es/articles/360028776572-Aumentar-el-tiempo-de-ejecución-de-PHP
Otra fuente:
https://mazer.dev/es/php/posts/php-timeout-max-execution-time/

Gracias por la respuesta.
El inconveniente no está tanto en que se agote el tiempo de espera realmente.
Esa petición tiene una respuesta instantánea, hay algo que debo estar haciendo mal para que no responda y el tiempo de espera se agote.
